# Include PHP codes inside PHP variable

Tags: php, html, sql, database, variables

How can I include this code as it is and then upload it to my database and in the database there should be variables and not strings?

CODE:

```
$username1 = $_SESSION['myusername'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username`='$username1'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $replytext = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td rowspan="10" class="teamimage" style="background-image: url(images/usericons/'.$row['img'].');"><div style="background-image:url(images/teamicons_shadow.png); width: 75px; height: 75px;"></div></td></tr><tr valign="top"><td rowspan="10" style="width:10px;"></td><td style="width:300px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"><tr><td class="teamname"><b><a href="teams.php?user='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['username'].'</a></b></td></tr><tr><td>Summoner Name: '.$row['summonername'].'</td></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888; padding-bottom: 5px;">Clan: '.$row['clan'].'</td></tr><tr><td style="color: #888; padding-top: 3px;">Country: '.$row['country'].'</td></tr><tr><td style="color: #888; padding-top: 3px;">Joined In: '.$row['created'].'</td></tr></table></td><td style="width:10px;"></td><td rowspan="10" style="border: 1px solid #aaa; padding: 3px; width:600px;">'.$replytext.'</td></tr></table>';
}
```

CODE IN DATABASE

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <tr>
     <td rowspan="10" class="teamimage" 
       style="background-image: url(images/teamicons/default_user.png);">
       <div
         style="background-image:url(images/teamicons_shadow.png); 
           width: 75px; height: 75px;">
       </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr valign="top">
     <td rowspan="10" style="width:10px;">
     </td>
     <td style="width:300px;">
```

Please note that the code I explained before is the one inside of `$replytext`!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking...

Comment: what do you mean "database and not strings"

Comment: What I want is to be able to echo this out later on from my database with the variables and not strings instead of my variables.

Comment: I would just have a table with a different column for each variable and then when you want to call those variables, you structure the table on THAT page and insert the variables where they belong (same structured table as you have above). Especially if every table you want to echo looks the same, then just add the variables to the database and call them out later.

Comment: It's just that next time I reply to a post another table will appear so there will be 2 tables instead of one and so on

Comment: I was trying to format your code a bit, and it seems your html is incomplete..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right , you want that the code in the database will be:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td rowspan="10" class="teamimage" style="background-image: url(images/teamicons/$row['img'].png)
```

Another solution is to have a unique char that won't make php think it's a variable.
For instance change the:

```
$row['img']
```

to

```
 ###row['img']
```

and when you pull this code from the database use a simple str_replace to replace the ###
symbol with $.

Of course you need to have a unique char , if you are using a simple char like "a" , it will change all the "a" chars in your code to $ ... not a very good idea.

Comment: I tried it but it just echo it out like this: 
'.$row['username']'.
Summoner Name: '.$row['summonername']'.
Clan: '.$row['clan']'.
Country: '.$row['country']'.
Joined In: '.$row['created']'.
'.$replytext'.'; } ?>

Comment: I just marked your answer as the one which did work out for me, but I can say that it didn't... However thanks to your answer it all ended up with a solution after hours of work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the single quotes like so:

```
$replytext = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td rowspan="10" class="teamimage" style="background-image: url(images/usericons/$row[\'img\']);"><div ...
```

Use the \ escape for all the array keys:

```
 url(images/usericons/$row[\'img\']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful ?

```
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
```

Not sure tho. Reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php